# How to set Django ForeignKey value as a typed integer in admin forms

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with a ForeignKey in Django. Right now the admin defaults to using a dropdown to select the value of that ForeignKey. What I want is to be able to type in the id of the referenced object there instead of using the dropdown.

I tried using django.forms.IntegerField instead of ChoiceField but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a [**`NumberInput`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) instead, so in the form you specify:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'of', 'fields', 'and', 'fkfield']
        widgets = {
            'fkfield': forms.NumberInput()
        }
```

where the `fkfield` is the name of the `ForeignKey` model field.